# c# Xamarin Forms: NavigationPage icon not showing

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have just created a portable app from the default (app.cs) template, changed none of the code (although it seems I had to update Xamarin.Forms to fix a startup exception) and ran it.  I got this (No icon showing):

[image]

Just to be thorough, here is the code (once again, nothing changed from the template):

```
namespace App3
{
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            var content = new ContentPage
            {
                Title = "App3",
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {
                            HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            MainPage = new NavigationPage(content);
        }
```

Droid project, main activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "App3", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

However, when I run the ModelessAndModel app from Petzold's book (chapter 24  Source can be found [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples)), I get this (Icon showing!):

[image]

Nothing special in code. app.cs:

```
   public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
        }
...
```

MainPage.cs:

```
namespace ModelessAndModal
{
    public class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            Title = "Main Page";

            Button gotoModelessButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "Go to Modeless Page",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
            };
            gotoModelessButton.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new ModelessPage());
            };

            Button gotoModalButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "Go to Modal Page",
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
            };
            gotoModalButton.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ModalPage());
            };

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    gotoModelessButton,
                    gotoModalButton
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

droid project MainActivity.cs:

```
[Activity(Label = "ModelessAndModal", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

I'm sure, it is something simple, but I can't seem to find what the key diffrence is.  **What does it take to have my app have the icon show up in the navigation pane?**

Comment: I think the difference may be that Petzold's sample is using `FormsApplicationActivity` while new templates use `FormsAppCompatActivity` as the base class for `MainActivity`.

Comment: This worked for me (my icon just happens to be transparent):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55188043/xamarin-navigation-bar-has-unwanted-default-icon-impossible-to-alter-or-remove/55188439#55188439

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a Forms app using `FormsAppCompatActivity`, I believe that the way to add an icon to the toolbar is to do it in the .axml file for the Toolbar in the Android app project. The default layout for the toolbar in a new template Forms app is:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

But you can add controls to this, e.g. to add an icon:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

If there is a better way to do this, I have yet to find it.

Comment: Tested and it works.  I'm quite open to other ways to do this, but this way works, So, I'm quite happy with it

Comment: But this is not the same thing. this adds it for all pages. what if you want to add icon for only 1 page?

Comment: Actually it is the same thing. The icon never shows by default when using the `FormsAppCompatActivity` as the base class for the Android `MainActivity`, so this answer resolved that issue. What you are asking is a different question, so please post a new question.

Comment: That question has been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180189/navigationpage-settitleicon-works-on-ios-but-not-android/42181176?noredirect=1#comment75754290_42181176.  And I would love an answer.  Until then, our Android app doesn't look as good as iOS.

Answer (score 0):

"app:logo" also works with FormsAppCompatActivity:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
        app:logo="@drawable/icon" />
```

but "app:navigationIcon" still doesn't work (Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.270)

Comment: This works fine! But if you do it this way you can't control the position of the icon (e.g. center horizontal). Also you need to to add the following line to make it work:
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"