# NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon - works on iOS but not Android

Tags: xamarin

I added

NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(this, "LogoLocales.png");

Looks like it should work fine, but only works on iOS not Android.

Any ideas?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1mrd.png)

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/LogoLocales"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

to the toolbar.axml

and there you goooo...

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem, but I don't have a toolbar.axml and don't even know what that is.  Can you be more specific?  I tried some ActionBar related code from another thread, but MainActivity.ActionBar is always null and my NavigationPage bar doesn't look anything like an Android ActionBar anyways.

Comment: @EliotGillum Sorry I'm late, I'd suggest the above implementation, but here's a post that's a little more thorough into where to add it:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098078/2101268

Comment: Ok, I don't know how I missed it before, but I found my Toolbar.axml and this did work--for a static image.  But the question, and my exact problem, is setting this in code because there are times when it needs to change.

Comment: Hi guys, is there a way to display the icon on a single page only on Android?
There is no problem on iOS, but I don't see how to achieve it on Android...