# Xamarin.Forms: how to assign an icon to the Navigation Bar to a single page on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, android-imageview, android-toolbar, navigationbar

I try to use an icon instead of the title on the main page of my **Xamarin.Forms** app.

I've read a lot of related topics, but I didn't found any solution:

- [navigationpage-settitleicon](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/52337/navigationpage-settitleicon)
- [navigationpage-settitleicon-works-on-ios-but-not-android](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/88482/navigationpage-settitleicon-works-on-ios-but-not-android)
- [toolbar-title-set-center-align](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59722/toolbar-title-set-center-align)
- [xamarin-forms-custom-toolbar-android](http://xamarin-forms-custom-toolbar-android)
- [navigationpage-settitleicon-works-on-ios-but-not-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180189/navigationpage-settitleicon-works-on-ios-but-not-android)

On **iOS** this is done easily by adding this on my first page:

```
NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon(this, "navbar_logo.png");
```

On **Android**, I've added this on ***Toolbar.axml***:

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/navbar_adp_logo" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

This works, but the icon is now visible on each page on Android...

I've tried to use a **renderer** to hide the icon when I navigate to another page. For this I would like to use the override ***OnViewAdded()*** method:

```
public class CustomNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer 
{   
    public override void OnViewAdded(Android.Views.View child)   
    {  ...   } 
}
```

I try to use ***OnViewAdded()*** cause I've seen in **QuickWatch** that this method is called each time that I navigate in my Xamarin.Forms app.

I've also noticed that the method is called 2 times during navigation:

- the first time, the child parameter is a ***V7.Widget.Toolbar***:

[image: V7.Widget.Toolbar]

- the second time, the child parameter is a ***Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PageContainer***:

[image: PageContainer]

So I tried to cast the child into ***Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PageContainer***, but I can't do it because this object is "internal":

> PageContainer is inaccessible due to its protection method.

***Why couldn't I do it in code, if I can do it with QuickWatch?
I don't see if there is another way to achieve this...
Would you have any suggestion?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the `OnElementChanged` method and look for changes to the `CurrentPage` property. That way you'll always know when a specific page is shown and can hide or show the toolbar icon.

```
protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

    if (e.PropertyName.Equals("CurrentPage"))
        // If we're on MainPage show the icon, otherwise hide it
        ChangeToolbarIconVisibility(Element.CurrentPage is MainPage); 
}

private void ChangeToolbarIconVisibility(bool visible) 
{
    var toolbarIcon = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.toolbarIcon);        
    toolbarIcon.Visibility = visible ? Android.Views.ViewStates.Visible : Android.Views.ViewStates.Gone;            
}
```

To make this work, remember to add the id to your modified Toolbar layout:

```
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/navbar_adp_logo" 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:id="@+id/toolbarIcon" />
```

Comment: Could you share the custom render you made? @hankide please I tried to create it, however it is not being fired at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using messaging center and define what you want to do. Let say you want on your MainPage to set an icon and the rest to remove it.You can use something like:

On not main page:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Page, string>(this, "toolbar", "notmain");
```

On main page:

```
MessagingCenter.Send<Page, string>(this, "toolbar", "main");
```

You subscribe for those message in your MainActivity like below.

```
var toolbarIcon = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.navbar_adp_logo);

                //recommendation: do not use lambda, define a delegate function
                MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Page, string>(this, "toolbar", (page, toolbar) =>
                {
                    if (toolbar == "main")
                    {
                        toolbarIcon.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        toolbarIcon.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                    }

                });
```

Don't forget to define in xaml

```
 android:id="@+id/navbar_adp_logo"
```

If you want it only on one page then instead of sending messages from each page you can do the follow once on the page required

```
        protected override void OnDisappearing()
        {
            base.OnDisappearing();

            MessagingCenter.Send<Page, string>(this, "toolbar", "notmain");
        }

        protected override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            MessagingCenter.Send<Page, string>(this, "toolbar", "main");
        }
```

Comment: Your solution works really good and it is elegant. However, due to a Xamarin.Forms bug where the event OnAppearing and OnDisappearing gets fired twice that solution won't work. Here more information about the bug: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/1438 I will vote this answer up due I feel it is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: I don't see a big problem if visibility is set twice but you can add boolean flag to catch if disappearing is fired after appearing to work around that.